# Assigning TSQL Variable to SQLCMD Variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlcmd

I have two environments that I use to develop in and I want to be able to run other scripts from within another script. Currently when I need to switch between the two environments I have to manually comment out the path that I don't need:

```
--:SETVAR scriptPath "D:\Scripts\Mark\Documents\Data Integrations\"
:SETVAR scriptPath "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Data Integrations\"
:r $(scriptPath)"General Scripts"\"Functions and Setup".sql
```

This code runs fine but what I would like to do is to add a branching statement to automatically select the correct Path.

```
:SETVAR ServerName "(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS NVARCHAR(100)))"
DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF $(ServerName) = 'Computer1'
     SELECT @Path = 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Data Integrations\'
ELSE
     SELECT @Path = 'D:\Scripts\Mark\Documents\Data Integrations\'

:SETVAR scriptPath @Path
:r $(scriptPath)"General Scripts"\"Functions and Setup".sql
```

but with this code I am getting a "A fatal scripting error occurred.
Cannot find directory in the path specified for ":r" command. error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use directory names without spaces for test. I think some directory name with space symbol inside is not double quoted. So look through your script thoroughly to make sure that space doesn't break any path.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign use T-SQL variables in SQLCMD commands directly. The only way to achieve what you want is via an external file.

```
:Setvar DataPhysicalFile ""
:Out $(TEMP)\Rename-DB.temp
PRINT ':Setvar DataPhysicalFile "' +  @DataPhysicalFile + '"';
GO
:Out stdout
:r $(TEMP)\Rename-DB.temp
PRINT "$(DataPhysicalFile)"
GO
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me though I had to amend slightly.

:Setvar DataPhysicalFile "MyFile"
:Out $(TEMP)\Rename-DB.txt
PRINT ':Setvar DataPhysicalFile "' +  '$(DataPhysicalFile)' + '"';
GO
:Out stdout
:r $(TEMP)\Rename-DB.txt
PRINT '$(DataPhysicalFile)'
GO

Comment: Ignore that.  It was fine as it was.  It's the end of a Friday.